# Are there properties that differ in parameters and return type?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class call `CalcArray` that has an array of doubles called `Amounts()`, and two `ints`, `StartPeriod` and `EndPeriod`.

The user almost always wants to interact with the items in the array, not the Periods or the object itself. So ideally, I'd like:

```
property AnAmount() as CalcArray 'So the user can talk to the object if they need to
property AnAmount(i as Integer) as Double 'So the user can just get the value directly
```

This seems to work sometimes and not others. Is this simply a syntax issue? or is such an overload not possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may be bumping into the limitation that a function or property cannot vary by only the return type. In general if the signature has changed, the output type can change also on an overload. Look out also for the limitation for using default properties requires an argument. In some cases class inheritance is the issue, properties and functions being shadowed may explicitly be required to nominate Shadows, Overloads, Overrides etc. or the shadowing will be disallowed by the language.

If these don't cover the cases you've seen, try to catch an example of the problem and study all locations of the same named property in your solution, reporting the results here.

Comment: Ok, then it seems *possible* and I will assume it's just my syntax etc. Thanks, I just couldn't find a clear statement on this elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a **function** returning a different based on how it is called.  Especially since you have a param, a function might be more appropriate:

```
Public Function AnAmount(Of T)(parm As SomeType) As T
```

to use it:

```
Dim n as Decimal
n = AnAmount(Of Decimal)(foo)
```

Its very useful as a way to avoid returning an object and then have to use CType to convert the return.  In this case, an **amount** implies a value type, but the function would accept Point, Rectangle etc as T, so you might need to check valid type requests.

Comment: I didn't see this the first time around, thanks for the pointer in the other thread. I'm not sure I totally understand how to use it though... in my case the sig might be `Public Function DetailRows(Of T)() As ICollection`? Is there anything I have to do in the func body to make that work? Or is this simply a short-form for DirectCast?

Comment: It applies more to the `Function One...` portion of the question before the edits.  `T` allows you to pass any supported `Type` to the method.  You can also do `Function DetailRows(Of T, TT)(params) As TT` that would allow you to specify a different return type (TT) than received.  If the return is for Com then TT will be limited - Com chokes on generics