# Why can't I have two methods with the same parameters but different returns?

Tags: vb.net, generics

.net allows...

```
Public Function One(A as Integer) As String...
Public Function One(B as String) As String...
```

It figures out which one to call by looking at the Type of the parameters, like...

```
Dim A As String = One(5)
```

Ok, so why can't you do this...

```
Public Function One(A as Integer) As String...
Public Function One(B as Integer) As Integer...
```

The same amount of information is available to the compiler...

```
Dim A As Integer = One(5) ' should know to call the second version
```

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is to return the `Values` in a `Dictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)` so that it **is visible to COM Interop**. To do that I simply return the `.Values` as `IEnumerable`. But then I lose the type inside my own code, which is a PITA. If I could have two methods I could have one that returns IEnumerable and another that returns List(Of MyClass) and the API would be the same in both places. I could have two different method names, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

I'm open to any solution that fixes the underlying problem... is there a single type I can return that avoids all the DirectCast in my own code, while still being visible to COM Interop?

Comment: You could return an `IEnumerable(Of T)` right?

Comment: Consider that you aren't required to use the return value of a function. Perhaps the function has side-effects and you only care about the side effects, so you call it and then toss the return value in the trash without setting it to anything. Now how does the compiler know which one to call? It doesn't.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just have two different names for the methods?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/22198530/1070452, ironically its also your question

Comment: Like plutonix wrote, your previous question does have the answer to this one.

Comment: `Dim A As Object = One(5)`...which one does it call now?

Comment: @BillyONeal I'll try that on Monday, and I'll be very happy if it works. But previous attempts to send out anything typed failed. To everyone else: the key difference here is COM Interop. I've found innumerable cases where the side effect that COM only sees the first of co-named functions/subs/props to be very useful, but in this case I'm stymied. And Steven, of course I can do that, but it means documenting different APIs in different places, and thus confusion for no good reason.

Comment: @BillyONeal - That didn't work, you can see the error in the compiler output - it doesn't export the method if you have anything like (Of x) *sigh* seemed like an elegant solution.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin It would call an error. Just like it would if the input parameters had no match.

Comment: @Maury: Erm, no, I don't see any compiler output. There's no reason returning a `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)` should behave any differently than returning a `System.Collections.List`.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz That was my point.  It was a question intended to make you think about why you can't do what you were asking.

Comment: @BillyONeal It's because I am exporting to COM Interop. Try putting a `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : because the return type isn't included in the method's signature

### the relevant part of the [spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711868%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The following are not part of a member's signature, and hence cannot be overloaded on:
>
> - Modifiers to a type member (for example, `Shared` or `Private`).
> - Modifiers to a parameter (for example, `ByVal` or `ByRef`).
> - The names of the parameters.
> - The return type of a method or the element type of a property.